# How to disable interpolation in ListDensityPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

As an example

```
ListDensityPlot3D[
 Partition[
  Flatten@Table[{i, j, k, If[Mod[i, 2] == 0, 1, 0]}, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1,
      5}, {k, 1, 5}], 4],
 PlotLegends -> True]
```

gives

[image]

But my data value are discrete and composed of only 0 and 1, I don't want `ListDensityPlot3D` to do interpolation for me.

I want something like the different between

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[x y, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[x y, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

So is there any way to make 3D density plot similar to `InterpolationOrder->0` like `ListDensityPlot`?

Comment: I understand that `ListDensityPlot3D` does a smooth plot of the points represented. I find logical what MMA does, i.e., `Interpolation`. I think you should think about other plotting commands. In fact, I see that your points in the example are located in separated discrete planes, so what about `ListPointPlot3D`? Unless you want to do interpolation in those planes. In this case I suggest to combine with `Show`...

Comment: Hi, @JoséAntonioDíazNavas. Thank you for reply. But I don't want something like `ListPointPlot3D`. I have updated my post, maybe it is clearer now

Answer (score 2):

maybe this?

```
Show[Image3D[Table[
  If[Mod[i, 2] == 0, 1, 0],
   {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}]], axes->True]
```

[image]

Comment: ， Thank you so much, This works